# Access- Where and OR not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join, where-clause

I have the following query written in MS Access

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ColumnA, Table1.ColumnB,Table1.ColumnC,Table1.ColumnD,Table1.ColumnE
FROM Table2 
RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON (Table2.ColumnB = Table1.ColumnF) 
WHERE (Table1.ColumnF <>28) OR (Table1.ColumnF<>29)
```

1. Tried to with and without Parentheses
2. When I just have one where statement the 262 records go down to 160 records, as expected
3. When I have the two conditions connected by the OR, the records go back up to 262, clearly not doing whats expected. Even if just the first condition held, I should not have gone back up to 262 records.

My question is whats wrong with my query, especially as it pertains to the WHERE XXX OR XXX?

Secondly, does the RIGHT JOIN statement have any bearing on the outcome of a subsequent WHERE statement.

Thirdly, if I cannot combined a RIGHT JOIN and a WHERE, what is the optimal way to apply conditions to a query that relies on a RIGHT JOIN?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace your OR with AND

```
 WHERE (Table1.ColumnF <>28) AND (Table1.ColumnF<>29)
```

Comment: Why would you use an AND? Wouldnt that mean both conditions have to be fulfilled? In my case the moment a 28 is seen that record should be omitted, a 29 main not occur till a later record.  @Jason

Comment: because "(X <> 28) OR (X <> 29)" is TRUE for any value of X, including 28 and 29.

Comment: @jacobronniegeorge If ColumnF is 28, then your WHERE clause reduces to `(28 <> 28) OR (28 <> 29)` which reduces to `(FALSE) OR (TRUE)` which is true. Therefore no rows are eliminated by the WHERE clause

Comment: Oh boy, that was dumb of me wasnt it???? @ Jason, @Tobsey makes it much clearer appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this instead:

```
WHERE Table1.ColumnF Not In (28,29)
```

That approach expresses your intention clearly and concisely.  Now that you have resolved the issue of `OR` vs. `AND` for your `WHERE` conditions, this suggestion probably doesn't seem very useful.  However, keep it in mind for when you have several more such conditions. `Not In (28,29,32,40,119)` will be easier to write and understand than 4 `AND` s.

Comment: Now based on this particular statement, how would you incorporate another additional condition, that Column G IS NUL...and if Column G is NULL keep that value and do not omit?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking there.  Do you mean this? ... `WHERE ColumnG Is Null AND ColumnF Not In (28,29)` ... IOW, to return a row, both the ColumnG and ColumnF conditions must be satisfied?

Comment: Let me expound: I have a list of 127 Records, the two pertinent columns Column F( Owner ID1) and Column G(Owner ID2).  If and only if in Column F 28 or 29 occurs, and in Column G there is no value should they be omitted.  So logically 1. Check to see that Column F has a 28 or 29 2. If it does have a 28 or 29, then check to see that Column G for that row is null, 3. If null then leave it dont omit, 4. otherwise omit rows that have a value in Column G

Comment: I'm struggling to understand.  Suggest you submit a new question with a brief set of input data and your desired results, both in tabular format.